# Windows Phone app button requires two presses to fire its action

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a button inside of a stackpanel that has to be pressed twice to execute its action. This only happens when I hide the stackpanel and show it again.

First, I press the button and the stackpanel is hidden, hiding the button. I press another button that brings the stackpanel back. I click the button, doesn't work. Click again, and it works.

This happens in the emulator and in the phone.

This is the xaml I have:

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Name="myPanel">
      <Button Content="{Binding LocalizedResources.ButtonX, Source={StaticResource Localization}}" Name="btnX" Click="btnX_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

In the code, I just control the visibility as shown below:

```
myPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it works when I force the focus on the button, just after I make the panel visible. Wondering why....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the stack panel `Focus` upon return to the page. The double click comes from the fact that the first click is giving the control `Focus` the second is then allowing your embedded control to be activated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You answered at the same time as I discovered it. Bit strange behavior, imho. Thanks for the answer ;)